# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 xlsx External table is not in the expected format large file

Tags: c#, oledb, xlsx

I've been using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to read xlsx files into a c# application.
It always works in my development environment. In the production environment I get this error message when trying to read in larger files: "External table is not in the expected format".

-same file imports fine in development environment.
-if I split the file up into smaller (<~1000 rows per file) it/they import/s fine in the production environment.

I keep seeing posts with similar keywords, but they usually don't contact the "only a problem with larger files" detail.

Any ideas?

I guess 2 clarifying questions:

1) Why would a large-file-problem generate such a generic off topic error message?
2) IS there a memory(limit) setting I can change that may help?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like this one is pretty closely related, but my app is not a web app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343344/unable-to-read-xlsx-file-through-oledb-with-the-size-more-than-1mb

Comment: update / note: I just had another larger xlsx file to read and discovered the error only seems to occur when run as a scheduled task, which is still a problem.